# Agregar fila a una tabla sobre otra fila

Tags: javascript, php, html

tengo una tabla donde a través de javascript agrego filas, todo bien, pero tengo el requerimiento de que la fila agregada recientemente debe estar por encima de las demás filas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

comparto codigo donde realizo esto

```
var id_row = 'row' + cant;
var zona = '<tr id="' + id_row + '"> <td> <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="idZona[]" value="' + datosZona[0].idZona + '"> <label class="form-control">' + datosZona[0].nombreZona + '</label></td>';

var elementoFondeo = '<td> <input type="hidden"  name="idElementoFondeo[]" value="' + datosElementoFondeo[0].idElementoFondeo + '"><label class="form-control"> ' + datosElementoFondeo[0].nombreElementoFondeo + '</label</td>';

var observacion = '<td> <input type="hidden" name="idObservacionElementoFondeo[]" value="' + datosObservacionElementoFondeo[0].idObservacionElementoFondeo + '"><label class="form-control"> ' + datosObservacionElementoFondeo[0].observacionElementoFondeo + '</label</td>';
                            
var estado = '<td> <input type="hidden" name="idEstadoElementoFondeo[]" value="' + datosEstadoElementoFondeo[0].idEstadoElementoFondeo + '"><label class="form-control">' + datosEstadoElementoFondeo[0].nombreEstadoElementoFondeo + '</label></td>';

var imagen = '<td> <input type="hidden" name="urlImagenElemento[]" value="' + base64String + '"><label class="form-control"> ' + nombreImagenElemento + '</label></td>';

var btnEliminar = '<td><a class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="eliminar(' + cant + ')">Eliminar</a></td></tr>';

var fila = zona + elementoFondeo + observacion + estado + imagen + btnEliminar;

$("#tablaFondeo").append(fila);
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes cambiar `append` por [prepend](https://api.jquery.com/prepend/), ejemplo:

```
$("#tablaFondeo").prepend(fila);
```

- append : inserta al final
- prepend: inserta al principio

---

Si lo que necesitas es agregar después del primero puedes ocupar [after](https://api.jquery.com/after/), para ello debes seleccionar el elemento (en tu caso el primero) y luego con after agregas algo despúes de éste

Ejemplo:

```js
$("#tablaFondeo tr").first().after("<tr><td>77</td></tr>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id="tablaFondeo">
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: funciona, pero no es lo que busco, la agrego sobre la fila donde se insertar los datos, muchas gracias! @yussef

Comment: @JavierSanhueza he editado mi respuesta, espero te sirva. Caso contrarío me avisas para volver a cambiar